# Python Sockets: receive udp packets any destination

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I want to code a packet analyzer with python running on an raspberry pi.
It should analize OSC (open sound control) and Art-Net (stage lighting protocol). Both are UDP packets - I use the following code, found here: http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

while True:
    print s.recvfrom(65565)
```

Everything works fine, if the desination ip is the ip of the raspberry pi. I want to receive all udp traffic in the network, also packets not addressed to the raspberry pi to show also packets send by servers to another client.

What can I change here to do that?

Comment: dont receive if haven't any `bind`. `socket.IPPROTO_UDP` only recive your packet. what is `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)`, `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 3)`, `s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)`

Comment: changed that to 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 3)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

now got error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ArtSniffer/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 92] Protocol not available

Comment: Now it works under windows - but also no packets from "not my ip"

Comment: I troubleshooted with wireshark, it also does'nt capture OSC packets with another IP than mine. Same via wifi or cable.

Comment: UDP packets required 2 socket binding (server, client) , you can't grab UDP packets if your device(ETH) is'nt a gateway !  So you can't collect data if connection type is Point_To_Point (UDP). Some switches clone all packets and push to all channels(Ports) (Not a gateway) and you can dumps all packets. Define a redirector before gateway for dumps every packet(Redirector: `Clients ---> Gateway ---> Your_Machine --> Gateway --> Global_interface` or `Clients ---> Your_machine --> Gateway  --> Global_interface`).

Comment: @dsgdfg all switches flood a packet to all ports (except the port that received the packet) if a switch hasn't got the destination MAC in its MAC address table.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 You can create udp socket from un-owned MAC and IP. Which avaible, which used, which allocated ?  You can't dump all udp-packets on same network(**not bidirectional dump(check previous suggestion)**) ! UDP require an external brodcasting for declared master/fake ports/ips. Same network not allowed  sniffing whole  point_to_point data ! Like this: `bind( server:1800) --> Accept(client:2200) --> Create_session_with_new_settings(server:3500)--> Accept(client:5500)` can't connect to (or whatever) `server:3500` if haven't any token ! Dumping DGRAM but how to archive data(pointer?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sniffing a network is a bit different from sniffing data incoming to a single machine. Sniffing a network unfortunately may require some infrastructural changes and has little to do with coding (your code will still be useful without large modifications).

#### Observing Ethernet network

A couple of terms you need to know here: [collision domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain), [broadcast domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain). If your whole network is in the same collision domain, just add a sniffer to the network and you should be able to observe the packets (at least with wireshark, not sure about the code you posted).

Collision domains are untouched by [ehternet hubs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub). Collision domains are separated by active network equipment ([routers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) and [switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch)). Broadcast domains are separated by routers or by switches between [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN)s. Being in a separate collision domain means you won't see point-to-point datagrams. Being in in different broadcast domains means you won't see broadcast and multicast datagrams.

If the whole network is connected to a single switch, you can setup port mirroring here. It copies traffic from one ehternet switch port (please note it's physical port, not a TCP/UDP one) to another in addition to basic switching process. For Cisco devices the technology is called [SPAN](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/10570-41.html).

Multiple switches + routers topology may require setting multiple SPANs across the equipment. If you have a single machine that orchestrates the lighting you may want to place sniffer there. Again, collecting network traffic requires architectural decisions.

#### Observing wireless network

This can be simpler because such a network always has single collision domain, so you can just get the packets from the air. But this openness also made wireless protocols more secure by default. So if the network uses a secure hotspot, there's probably no chance to sniff without committing unethical things. However, a hotspot is a router, and this router may be wired-connected to some switch. Here you can use port mirroring again.